# Executing Scala file of a project under SBT on commandline or in a text editor?

Tags: scala, vim, sbt

I am learning Scala with this coursera course task [here](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/programming/Ogg05/object-oriented-sets) that provides SBT file. I download its objsets.zip [here](http://alaska.epfl.ch/~dockermoocs/progfun1/objsets.zip). Then I unzip it end and enter into it and type `sbt` and then `console`. I try to load the file `src/main/scala/objsets/TweetSet.scala` on commandline but I am getting a lot of errors.

```
scala> :load src/main/scala/objsets/TweetSet.scala
Loading src/main/scala/objsets/TweetSet.scala...
<console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
package objsets
^
<console>:10: error: not found: value TweetReader
       import TweetReader._
              ^
import common._
defined class Tweet
<console>:2: error: illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here)
  override def toString: String =
  ^
```

the course uses Eclipse Scala IDE but I would like to learn to use Vim for Scala development, my favorite editor. I find Eclipse hard to use. So

*How can I load the scala files in the scala interpreter on the commandline under SBT? Does there exist some favourable tools for developing the scala project on a text editor such as Vim without having to leave the editor or commandline themselves?*

---

**SBT files and the directory looks like this**

```
$ tree src/
src/
├── main
│   └── scala
│       ├── common
│       │   └── package.scala
│       └── objsets
│           ├── TweetData.scala
│           ├── TweetReader.scala
│           ├── TweetSet.scala
│           └── testing.sc
└── test
    └── scala
        └── objsets
            └── TweetSetSuite.scala

7 directories, 6 files
$ cat build.sbt assignment.sbt 
name := course.value + "-" + assignment.value

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation")

// grading libraries
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.10" % Test

// for funsets
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-parser-combinators" % "1.0.4"

// include the common dir
commonSourcePackages += "common"

courseId := "bRPXgjY9EeW6RApRXdjJPw"

course := "progfun1"
assignment := "objsets"

assignmentInfo := AssignmentInfo(
  key = "6PTXvD99EeWAiCIAC7Pj9w",
  itemId = "d1FGp",
  premiumItemId = Some("Ogg05"),
  partId = "7hlkb",
  styleSheet = Some((_: File) / "scalastyle" / "scalastyle_config.xml")
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:load` copies the contents of a file into the REPL line by line. That means that you end up trying to define a package (which is not allowed in the REPL), and then you try to import things that aren't visible, etc. If you use `:load` on a file that has a format useable by the REPL, it will work. In most cases, this means replacing the `package` line(s) with `import`s.

There's no need to use `:load` anyway. `sbt console` will place you in a REPL that has the project on its classpath. `sbt consoleQuick` will place you in a REPL that only has the dependencies on the classpath.

For your second question, you are meant to use `sbt` as a background process. In your terminal emulator, you'll have one tab running `vim` on your files, and in the other tab, you'll have `sbt`. In the tab with `sbt`, you can run `~compile`, which recompiles your code every time you save a file in Vim. This replicates how IDEs show compiler errors/warnings as you type.

Comment: I found `~run` and `~compile` useful in developing things in Vim wihtout Eclipse Scala IDE, any idea whether any debugger available on the command line?

Comment: `jdb`: Java DeBugger